# Java - Weekly recurring calendar countdown

Tags: java, calendar, reset, recurring-events

I'm trying to make a countdown timer that will reset weekly (Mondays at 10am eastern). I've found something similar to what I'm looking for, but it doesn't reset itself; it goes into the negative. Can someone please help me get this working?

```
public static int SECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;

public String main(String[] args) {

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year  = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    Calendar reset = Calendar.getInstance();
    reset.setTime(new Date(0)); 
    reset.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1); //2
    reset.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    reset.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    reset.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //10
    reset.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 33);

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    long diff =  reset.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis(); 
    long diffSec = diff / 1000;

    long days = diffSec / SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
    long secondsDay = diffSec % SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
    long seconds = secondsDay % 60;
    long minutes = (secondsDay / 60) % 60;
    long hours = (secondsDay / 3600);

    if (diff < 0) {
        reset.setTime(new Date(0)); 
        reset.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1); //2
        reset.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        reset.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        reset.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //10
        reset.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 33);
    }

    return "Reset in: " + days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, and " + seconds + " seconds.";
}

public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e) {

    if(e.getMessage().getRawContent().equalsIgnoreCase(";reset")) {
        e.getChannel().sendMessage(main(null)).queue();
    }
}
```

I cant figure out how to make this reset once it reaches reset time. Any help very much appreciated. I haven't coded in 5+ years.

Below is screenshot of the output if the time has passed.

https://puu.sh/w3odJ/009663b380.png

Thanks!

UPDATE: I'm finding the best method for this is to use `reset.add` to add 7 days to the `reset` calendar. Can't get the proper conditions to be met to achieve this yet though. I've tried `reset.compareTo(today)` as well as some other combinations which aren't working, but it's progress.

Comment: Every attempt fails... Is not a description we can help with. Read [mcve] please. And I am not an android expert, but I am sure that there must be better means to trigger functionality in the future.

Comment: I can't get this to return a negative result, but if `diff` was negative, which would happen if the `reset` date was before `today`, then all the other values calculated would be negative, too.